# why am i getting these syntax errors when trying to implement system call

Tags: operating-system, linux-kernel, kernel

still working on this system call!!!

i have added a system call to a kernel, compiled and the OS is running off it.

now i am getting syntax error on the compilation of my test application.

testmycall.h

```
#include<linux/unistd.h>

#define __NR_mycall 244

_syscall1(long, mycall, int, i)
```

testmycall.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include "testmycall.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

    printf("%d\n", mycall(15));

}
```

here is the error

```
stef@ubuntu:~$ gcc -o testmycall testmycall.c
In file included from testmycall.c:3:
testmycall.h:7: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘mycall’
stef@ubuntu:~$ gcc -o testmycall testmycall.c
In file included from testmycall.c:3:
testmycall.h:7: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘mycall’
testmycall.h:7: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘i’
testmycall.c: In function ‘_syscall1’:
testmycall.c:7: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
testmycall.h:7: error: parameter name omitted
testmycall.h:7: error: parameter name omitted
testmycall.c:11: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
stef@ubuntu
```

i have added in the syscall instead of _syscall1

now i get this error

```
stef@ubuntu:~$ gcc -o testmycall testmycall.c
testmycall.c: In function ‘syscall’:
testmycall.c:7: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
testmycall.c:11: error: expected ‘{’
```

this is the app, any ideas why???

Comment: Please post the exact error you're getting.

Comment: Try looking at the preprocessed code - that may tell you (and us) more about the problem. Use gcc -E to output that and pay attention to the last part which is where the syntax error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`_syscall`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/_syscall.2.html) macros are obsolete and should not be used, instead use [`syscall`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscall.2.html), eg.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
...

printf("%d\n", syscall(__NR_mycall, 15));
```

---

Here's my test program:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define __NR_mycall 244

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%d\n", syscall(__NR_mycall,15));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: cheers man, this compiles for me, it must have been to do with the header file, dont really understand why though

Comment: getting -1 printed to the console? is that a problem with my system call

Comment: the system call should add 10 to the number supplied

Comment: @molleman: You should be using whatever number your syscall has been allocated, I simply used the value you supplied. you should also check `errno` for errors on failue

Comment: i have set #define __NR_mycall 244
__SYSCALL(__NR_mycall, sys_mycall) in unistd.h

 /usr/src/linux/include/asm-generic/unistd.h

Comment: i am using this http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Implement-Sys-Call-Linux-2.6-i386/ but modified for x86 arch, but im still lost

Comment: i dont know if i am modifying the correct files in the kernel

Comment: @molleman: Is `244` really not already occupied? ie. did you define it as the previous maximum system call number? (in my case `244` is ` __NR_get_thread_area`) I also note this tutorial seems to be somewhat old.

Comment: my problem is i dont know which unistd.h file i have to edit with the new system call and number

Comment: @molleman: You need to edit the `unistd.h` file in the kernel you are compiling (for your platform, if i386 then `include/asm-i386/unistd.h`), and use the same value as that. You might want to open a new question if you need further assistance

Comment: @Hasturkun ok i will do it if i dont understand the problem after this question. i have mine in include/asm-generic/unistd.h , now this file goes up to 244,(my 243 is #define __NR_recvmmsg 243
__SYSCALL(__NR_recvmmsg, sys_recvmmsg)) there are other unistd.h that are in folders such as arch/cris/include/asm and arch/frv/include/asm and arch/h8300/include/asm and arch/m32r/include/asm all of these have 244 as getthreadarea. but i have no idea which one to modify, im feeling lost at the moment, i running the latest linux kernel from ubuntu.

Comment: @molleman: use backticks for code comments. anyway, as I said, you need to edit the unistd.h file matching your target compilation platform, in your case you are probably running either on i386/i486/i686 or x86_64. run `uname -m` to find out.

Comment: my version is , i686, what folder would that correspond to in the `arch  folder, none of them say i686

Comment: @molleman: I don't really understand your last question. in any case, if you need help with the kernel modification, I suggest you ask in a separate question

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `_syscallN()` macros were removed from the kernel headers around 2.6.18 or so.

The (not especially helpful) error messages from gcc are due to `_syscall1` not being defined at all - you get the same errors if you write:

```
any_old_rubbish_here(long, mycall, int, i)
```

---

The `syscall()` function should work.  `man syscall` for details.